# SQL Server Query - Insert problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I'm having a problem with an insert query in SQL Server. The full text of the query is

```
insert into franchise (fran_id, name, address1, address2, city, state, zip, email, phone, text) 
values(0, "DevFranchise1", "101 Main St.", "-", "Brighton", "Mi", "48116", "dev1@franchisezippy.com", 8105551234, "asdflkjsadf");
```

Now "state" and "text" both highligh blue. It gives me a list of errors like the following:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'DevFranchise1'
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name '101 Main St.'
```

What does this mean / how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals should be in single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`).

Additionally, right angled brackets (`[]`) will allow you to use keywords (such as state and text) as column names. This is not always necessary, but provides a way out in ambiguous situations.

```
insert into franchise
    (fran_id, name, address1, address2, city, [state], zip, email, phone, [text])
values
    (0, 'DevFranchise1', '101 Main St.', '-', 'Brighton', 'Mi', '48116',
    'dev1@franchisezippy.com', 8105551234, 'asdflkjsadf');
```

Comment: and in the future I'd avoid using any keywords as a column name.  If it turns blue like you describe, you know something is up...

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, my first time working on an IIS server.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use single quotes (') instead of double (").

Otherwise, your values seem to be considered as column names.

Answer (score 2):

use Single quotes and it will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use single quotes in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use the single quote character not the double quote character in SQL

Answer (score 1):

```
set quoted_identifier off
```

before the insert.

But better is use single quotes.